# What's the best website to get the average base salaries for software developers?

Tags: salary

I think Payscale seems to be the most accurate. For a senior developer in Canada, they claim that the median base salary is 100k in Montreal, which seems in line with what I see on online job boards like Indeed. Is this really the most accurate places to get the median salary?

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are considered off-topic. "The best" changes continuously and is usually a subjective evaluation. In particular: Unless you can find a government -provided site, this is all glorified anecdotal evidence. And salary depends on *exactly* what the role is and on that company's  policies and practices, not on job title, especially not on such a broad job title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sites that report average salaries, or a salary range, can only do so based on what people tell them. The question is always do they have enough data points that are accurate, recent, and relevant to give a good estimate.

You give the example of senior developer in city x. The issue will be how many data points do they have, because the term senior developer is vague at best. You need to define senior, and there are many types of developers. Knowing something about cloud, or AI/ML might pay differently then one working on web applications; but they are still senior developers.